# Not able to fetch data from server in my ReactJs site

Tags: json, reactjs, http, backend

**Getting undefined data type error while fetching data from JSON**

I have searched at many places but didn't get the suitable answer

```
import SavedData from "./SavedData";

export default class Saved extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      datas: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const todoData = response.json().then((res) => {
      this.setState({ datas: res });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.datas[0].description);   //not able to get data
    return (
      <div>
        {/* {this.state.datas.map((items) => (
          <SavedData
            key={items.countTodo}
            title={items.title}
            desc={items.desc}
          />
        ))} */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Someone help me so that I can proceed**

Comment: Your render runs before the request has completed and you do not appear to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datas state is initially an empty array until your componentDidMount fires and sets the state.  As a result, your console log will then be undefined until the state is set. In order to combat this you must wait for this.state.datas[0] to be true before accessing the first objects description within the array.  The following code seems to work as expected

```
import React from "react";

export default class Saved extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      datas: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    response.json().then((res) => {
      this.setState({ datas: res });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.datas[0] && this.state.datas[0].description);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.datas.map((items, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <div> title={items.title}</div>
            <div> desc={items.description}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Dave Newton has pointed out in the comments, the render is triggered before the request completes. This is normal and you just need to handle it properly.

If you see the console logs of this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brown-m7ujb), you can see that initially `this.state.datas` is just an empty array `[]` - so any attempt to access `this.state.datas[0].description` will be `undefined`. Only after the state is updated when the request completes, the logs show the data retrieved - this is because according to the [mount lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting) of a React `Component`, the `render()` is called before the `componentDidMount()` and also the request being async.

This is very common and it is even recommended by the official React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call) to make HTTP calls in `componentDidMount()`. The docs also has provided an [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#example-using-ajax-results-to-set-local-state) to handle this issue.

```
import SavedData from "./SavedData";

export default class Saved extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,  // we initially set this to true
      datas: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const todoData = response.json().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        datas: res,
        loading: false  // when the request is complete, we set this to false
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      // during the first render, loading will be true and we
      // can return a loading message or a spinner
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }

    // when render is called after the state update, loading will be false
    // and this.state.datas will have the fetched data
    console.log(this.state.datas[0].description);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.datas.map((items) => (
          <SavedData
            key={items.countTodo}
            title={items.title}
            desc={items.desc}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As I was writing this answer, the URL `https://todo-list-site.herokuapp.com/todo-data` was returning some JSON data. But now, it seems to be returning an empty array `[]`. So, the codesandbox will show `[]` during the second `render()` as well (technically it is just showing the fetched data).